# chamar um arquivo pela ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart

Tenho uma duvida aparentemente simples(dificil pra mim que sou iniciante), mas eu criei um navigation drawer, e neste drawer tem as ListTile, preciso saber como chamar um arquivo por essa list.

```
ListTile(
              title: Text('Calculadora'),
              onTap: () {

                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
```

tenho um arquivo "`Calculator.dart`", mas nao sei qual a função que eu coloco pra mudar a pag.

Answer (score 1):

[Aqui tem alguns exemplos](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes) de como navegar entre páginas, note que há várias formas dependendo do seu uso.

Não dá pra saber ao certo como está a implementação de sua navegação, mas uma possível solução seria:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Calculator()),
);
```

Veja um exemplo básico rodando aqui: 
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ab9606eb3dcfb378425154d977d59e11